# pointer-to-method callbacks in C++11/14/17?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17, stdbind

(A previous question of mine has similar wording and examples, but is asking something quite different. 
 Before I was asking for ideas for approaches.  Now I'm asking how to get a specific approach to work.)

I have some subscription function that will call my callback when something happens.  (Let's say it's a timer, and will pass me an object when a certain number of milliseconds elapses.)  After looking at lambdas, `std:function` and `std:bind` I think the solution of pointers-to-methods is higher performance and simpler to write (especially for the subscriber) but I can't quite figure out the last bit.

This example mirrors my project a bit: we have a framework, represented by Foo, which is written once, and we'll have many subclasses represented here by Bar that will be written by people with more domain knowledge but less C++ knowledge.  So, we want that call to `SubscribeTimer()` to be as simple as possible.  Finally the application is high performance and we'd like to eliminate heap usage, including creating implicit `std::bind` objects and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class Data { int i; };

class Foo {
public:
    typedef void (Foo::*Timer_T)( Data* pd );
    virtual void SubscribeTimer( int iMilliseconds, Timer_T pmethod );
    virtual void SubscribeTimer( int iMilliseconds, std::function<void(Data*)> pfn ); // undesired

    virtual void OnTimerA( Data* pd ) { cout << "Foo::OnTimerA called" << endl; };
};

void Foo::SubscribeTimer( int iMilliseconds, Timer_T pmethod ) {
    Data d;
    (this->*pmethod)( &d );
}

void Foo::SubscribeTimer( int iMilliseconds, std::function<void(Data*)> pfn ) { // undesired
    Data d;
    pfn( &d );
}

class Bar: public Foo {
    public:
    void Init();
    virtual void OnTimerA( Data* pd ) { cout << "Bar::OnTimerA called" << endl; };
    virtual void OnTimerB( Data* pd ) { cout << "Bar::OnTimerB called" << endl; };
};

void Bar::Init() {
    // Works like I want it to: easy to subscribe, and high performance.
    SubscribeTimer( 1000, &Foo::OnTimerA );
    // What I'd like to do, but doesn't work.
    //SubscribeTimer( 1000, &Bar::OnTimerB );
    // Does exactly what I want except more complicated to write and I believe slower to run.
    SubscribeTimer( 1000, std::bind( &Bar::OnTimerB, this, std::placeholders::_1 ) );
}


int main( int nArg, const char* apszArg[] ) {
    Bar bar;
    bar.Init();
}
```

As expected (if you overlook the requirement to write `Foo::`, not `Bar::` in `Init()`'s call to `SubscribeTimer()`) the program outputs:

```
Bar::OnTimerA called  (from the version of SubscribeTimer() I like)
Bar::OnTimerB called  (from the version of SubscribeTimer() I think is too verbose/slow)
```

So this example works perfectly and does what I need... **except** that the subclass can only register handlers for method names the superclass has thought to define, whether or not they are defined or not.  In reality, though, the subclass may wish to register many handlers for different events, with names tha superclass wouldn't know.

So in a sentence: how can I pass `OnTimerB()` into the method-pointer version of `SubscribeTimer()`?  I'm happy to change `Timer_T` definition, `SubscribeTimer()` or whatever.  As a floor though, there is no point in a member-pointer solution more complicated for the *subclass* than the `std::function` implementation, and no point in a solution slower than the`std::function` implementation either.  On the other hand, added complexity in the *superclass* isn't a problem, as it's write-once code.

Answer (score 1):

To call `Bar::OnTimerB`, you need a pointer of type `Bar`. You therefore need to implement some kind of type erasure.

```
class Foo {
public:
  template <typename Derived>
  void SubscribeTimer(int iMilliseconds, void (Derived::*pmethod)(Data* pd)) {
    auto const self = static_cast<Derived*>(this);
    Data d;
    (self->*pmethod)(&d);
  }
};
```

Obviously, if you are going to have the callback invoked later, then you need to store this somehow. This is what `std::function<>` abstracts away for you. You could, of course, do that yourself, but `std::function<>` isn't that bad, especially on platforms with the small-function optimization.

You could therefore do the `std::function` wrapper internally:

```
  template <typename Derived>
  void SubscribeTimer(int iMilliseconds, void (Derived::*pmethod)(Data* pd)) {
    SubscribeTimer(iMilliseconds,
        [self = static_cast<Derived*>(this), pmethod](Data* pd) {
            (self->*pmethod)(pd);
        });
  }
```